# Windows keeps asking for password when resuming from hibernate

Tags: windows-10, passwords, hibernate, powercfg, panasonic-toughbook

I have an issue with a Panasonic CF-C2 laptop. There are three configured users, where only one is used to logon, the Administrator-account. The other two are used for specific software-applications programmed by a supplier.

When resuming the laptop from hibernation, the system should auto-logon. It **does** effectively auto-logon when rebooting, just not when resuming from a hibernated or sleeping state. I have configured everything that I think is possible to configure concerning passwords on wake/boot. Also, no screensaver with lock-option has been configured.

I'm starting to wonder if this can be disabled in hardware/BIOS-related settings (which sounds far-fetched, imho) or if this can have something to do with specific factory settings? We have approx. 100 Panasonic CF-54's where the problem **does not** appear. Same software installed, same user credentials, same powercfonfigs...

I'm at the end of my wits right now, any clue could be useful.

Thanks in advance!

I have skimmed the web for solutions and have so far taken the following steps:

Using **Local Group Policy Editor**

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings`
- Require a password when a computer wakes (plugged in) : DISABLED
- Require a password when a computer wakes (on battery) : DISABLED

`User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management`
- Prompt for password on resume from hibernate/suspend

Using **Powercfg**

Run both these commands on the 'current' scheme and all existing schemes (I scripted a tool to return the GUID's from the list and then run the SETACVALUE/SETDCVALUE for each of them
`powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0`
`powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0`

Using **Windows Settings -> Sign-in options**

Configured the "If you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?" to *Never*

Using **Registry editor**

`Computer\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
 - AutoAdminLogon set to 1
 - DefaultUserName is configured correctly
 - DefaultDomainName is configured correctly
 - DefaultPassword : I've tried this with an unencrypted password, no result

`HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\0e796bdb-100d-47d6-a2d5-f7d2daa51f51` (And other GUID's)
 - DCSettingIndex set to 0
 - ACSettingIndex set to 0

Using **Microsoft Sysinternals Autologon tool**

I've tried using this tool, but even then, nothing changes. No password is asked on reboot, still a password needed to resume from hibernate.

Using **control userpasswords2**

Disabled the option "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer"

Comment: Security nightmare aside what is actually happening if you resume from hibernation? What do you see?

Comment: Security nightmare, don't bother, we have tried explaining this to our customer but they won't change their views... Anyway... When I resume from hibernation, I see the small circle for a few seconds (Windows loading screen, black background with the dotted circle) and then it opens right onto the logon screen where the user has to click/swipe up to enter his password. The correct user is automatically selected for login, however...